# How to solve getSqlMapClientTemplate() method is undefined error despite packaging in correct JAR and using necessary import statement?

Tags: java, spring, ibatis

### **The Situation:**

I am working on bringing some *old* projects up so they comply with my company's upgrade to Java 8. Part of this requirement means upgrading from old versions of Spring to *at least* Spring version 3.2.3.RELEASE. The project I'm working under uses an ant build script to package everything into a deploy-able ear. I'm not too familiar with many build methods other than maven, so my knowledge on ant related subjects isn't great.

Before the upgrade, the project depended on Spring-1.0.2 and used methods from parts of the *dao* and *orm* package, specifically DataAccessException and getSqlMapClientTemplate(). There may be more being used, but those don't seem to have produced errors or I haven't found them yet (and are not included in the scope of this question).

### **The Issue:**

I have downloaded and placed spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE, spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE, spring-orm-3.2.3.RELEASE, spring-tx-3.2.3.RELEASE into the project (see **fig. 1** and **fig. 2**). Within many of the classes, we are calling the getSqlMapClientTemplate() method (see line 31 of **fig. 3**). I have found that, in Spring version 3.2.3, this method should be located in the *orm* package (source: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework/spring-orm/3.2.3.RELEASE). The import for the package is provided on line 17 of **fig. 3**. My understanding is that, with the correct JAR packaged in and the correct import statement included, the error should go away as it is defined within the project. This, however, does not seem to be the case (see **fig. 4**). The error states that the method is still not defined.

I might not have enough experience to know where things seem to be going wrong. I'm not really sure what to do, so any information that y'all might have would be awesome. I can provide more information as needed.

### **The Figures:**

[fig. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPkmk.png)

[fig. 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnIz5.png)

[fig. 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTGCe.png)

[fig. 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNNZ7.png)

Comment: Spring 5.x is current production.  Your effort to get to 3.2.3.RELEASE is wrong-headed.  Spring 1.x would be a crime against humanity.  You can't expect to have no changes.  Better to be current.

Comment: What we really need, is some code with some of your annotations if needed, instead of screenshots. The best would be to produce a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: duffymo, I don't disagree with you. 5.x would be the best case scenario, but I just joined the team, this code hasn't been touched in a decade, and I'm told we don't have the time to refactor for 5.

I'll try and work on a mvce, LoneWanderer.